# git push rejected, Pull Failed: fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Tags: git, github

I created new Repo on Github console.
In Android Studio, committed and trying to push to remote, Push getting rejected.

In studio, I'm able to make successfull connection with github.

tried Git pull using android studio, Got:

```
Git Pull Failed: fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

Even in git bash Got this:

```
>git push origin master<br/>
To https://github.com/XXXX.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/XXX.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Hey I solved my problem, that answer in the links clearly says " option to be used in a rare event that merges histories of two projects that started their lives independently.". my solution is easy and hopefully will help someone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In Android Studio,
```

Go to master, mater-->rebase onto-->
You get:

```
Rebase Successful: Rebased master on origin/master
```

Then Push with android studio.

[image]